# The position of the first non-digit char in the string

Tags: postgresql

How can I find the position of the first non-digit char in the string?

The function position seems do not support regular expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position` function doesn't supports regular expressions, so you should to write little bit more complex expression, or you can write your own function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.regexp_position(text, text)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE sql
 IMMUTABLE STRICT
AS $function$
SELECT position((regexp_match($1, $2))[1] IN $1)
$function$

postgres=# select regexp_position('abcdef123','\d');
┌─────────────────┐
│ regexp_position │
╞═════════════════╡
│               7 │
└─────────────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# select regexp_position('772727a','[^\d]');
┌─────────────────┐
│ regexp_position │
╞═════════════════╡
│               7 │
└─────────────────┘
(1 row)
```